# AS3 Using Event Dispatcher

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dispatchevent

I made a door/button and added as a class, i want it so when you click on it, it dispatches an event that signals a function in the main actionscript page to run

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Door extends MovieClip {

        var direct:String;
        var doorId:int;
        var dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();

        public function Door()  {
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeRoom)
            this.buttonMode = true;
        }

        function changeRoom(e:MouseEvent):void{
            trace("door click")
            dispatcher.dispatchEvent( new Event("doorClick") );
        }
    }
}
```

the main page looks like this

```
var doorTop = new Door();
doorTop.addEventListener("doorClick",goToRoom);
//should i be doing stage.addEventListener("doorClick",goToRoom);
function goToRoom(e:Event):void
{
  trace("i went here")
}
```

what am i doing wrong? seems straight forward enough

Answer (score 4):

You aren't dispatching the event from `doorTop`, you're dispatching it from `dispatcher` within `doorTop`.

`Door` extends `MovieClip` which extends `EventDispatcher`. You don't need to create an EventDispatcher, your `Door` class already is one.

Just do this:

```
    function changeRoom(e:MouseEvent):void{
        trace("door click")
        this.dispatchEvent( new Event("doorClick") );
    }
```

That will dispatch it from the `Door` object.

Additionally, if you are using classes, every single object (including functions) declared within the top-level scope of a class must include an access modifier (public, private, internal, or protected). You cannot just declare `function changeRoom`, it must be `public function changeRoom`. Same with each of your variables.

Comment: I have a question, what if the class doesn't extend the Event Dispatcher, what would be the correct way in doing it? Once it has been received how can identify who called it?

Comment: If you need to use events with a class, you should **always** make it extend `EventDispatcher`. You should never instantiate an actual EventDispatcher within your code. There is nothing stopping you (you would attach the listener to `object.dispatcher` in this case, rather than `object`), but you shouldn't even need to. The majority of objects already extend EventDispatcher, too

Comment: thank you, what can i use to identify who dispatched the event? something like this.target.e?

Comment: `Event.target` is the original object to dispatch the event. `Event.currentTarget` is the latest object to dispatch the event. Difference is best explained in a button. If you click on a button, you might actually click on the text in the button. This would be the `target`. The event would bubble up (read up on event bubbling) and the button object would also dispatch it, making it the `currentTarget` (`currentTarget` will *always* be the object you attached the listener to)

Comment: A class need not *extend* EventDispatcher. The minimum requirement is implementing IEventDispatcher. In question's code, if dispatching class wasn't EventDispatcher (hypothetically), then OP could have implemented implemented IEventDispatcher::(addEventListener,removeEventListener,dispatchEvent) which wrapped composed dispatcher object and that would have worked too. (See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html#includeExamplesSummary)

Comment: All objects that can listen to themselves for click events are also EventDispatchers.

Comment: Do I really need to declare all my function public or private? I thought in as3 they default to private. So i only really need to declare public

Comment: Depends on your IDE. You should **always** declare it, though. It is good practice and depending on IDE, will save you warning and even error headaches.

Comment: The default access modifier is internal, not private. Meaning it's available in the same package.